# onclick expand bubble and show details in d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In the d3js bubble chart shown in the following link : http://www.knightfoundation.org/features/civictech/

once click on **Explore** bubble chart will appear...

the bubble should expand and show details in side div  when it is clicked .

i achived normal expansion in bubble chat but i need as the above scenario 
..
I want to implement that feature in my d3js bubble chart. Does anyone know how to do implement ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Assign on("click", function () { do your stuff here}) to each bubble. Inside the function you can use D3 or jQuery to populate your div's with the info about this node (d).

Comment: Thanks klaujesi,  as per your suggestion i done maxiumpart but i need on mouseover on node a line should be create and it will point to another node ...can you ple suggest as in the above url